# EntityFramework Custom Association

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Ok lets say i have a user table and then a table that logs all login atempts (Id(counter), userId, time and if successful or not)

Now in my Entity Model i want it to be 2 Association's one with the time of all successful attempts and one with all unsuccessful attempts how could i achieve this?

This is how the model looks now!

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Good question. :)

What your essentially trying to do is have a *condition* on your **navigational property**, like how you have have *conditional mapping* on your **entities**.

*Unfortunately*, Navigational Properties on the conceptual model must map to foreign keys on the physical model (database). And FK's cannot be conditional.

**What i would do**, is use TPH on **UserLoginHistory**.

Create two entities - **UserLoginHistorySuccess** and **UserLoginHistoryFail**.

And use a dicriminator (**Success**) to map to the single **UserLoginHistory** table.

E.g:

- UserLoginHistorySuccess - maps to UserLoginHistory when Success = 1
- UserLoginHistoryFail - maps to UserLoginHistory when Success = 0

That way, you can add two navigational properties on **User**, which maps to the two entities.

But you still only require 1 actual database table.

More on Table Per Hierachy [here](http://www.robbagby.com/entity-framework/entity-framework-modeling-table-per-hierarchy-inheritance/).

Good luck!